# Delete Text from TextBoxes and Shapes in Current Slide or All Slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to 'Delete Texts' from All Slides or Current Slide depending on my choice.

I have textboxes that I needed to clear all at once and I also want to choose whether to Delete from all Slides or just this Current Slide.

I getting the error

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

on `For Each sh In Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide`

I copied some of the code from Microsoft.

```vb
Sub ClearAllTextBox()
    Dim sh          As Shape
    Dim sld         As Slide
    Dim SldDelType  As Boolean
    
    SldDelType = False
    
    Select Case MsgBox("Delete Texts From All Slides?", vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel)
        Case vbYes:
            SldDelType = True
        Case vbNo:
            SldDelType = False
        Case vbCancel:
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Select Case MsgBox("Are you Sure you want To Delete " & vbNewLine & "all Text from all Shapes/TextBoxes?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo)
        Case vbNo:
            Exit Sub
        Case vbYes:
            If SldDelType Then
                For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
                    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
                        If sh.HasTextFrame Then
                            sh.TextFrame.DeleteText
                        End If
                    Next sh
                Next sld
            Else:
                For Each sh In Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
                    If sh.HasTextFrame Then
                        sh.TextFrame.DeleteText
                    End If
                Next sh
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each sh In Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop over all shapes of a slide, you need to say so. You are doing it right already in the upper part, there you write `For Each sh In sld.Shapes`. You need to do the same if you want to loop over all shapes of a single slide:

```
    (...)
Else
    For Each sh In Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes
        If sh.HasTextFrame Then
        (...)
        End If
    Next sh
End If
```

or use a slide variable to split that long statement:

```
Else
    Set sl = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    For Each sh sl.Shapes
        (...)
    Next sh
End If
```